# How to install CKAN from source on RedHat?

Tags: ckan

We are trying to install CKAN on RedHat and experiencing variety of issues.

This is what we were trying to follow, but did not succeed.
https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.0/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html

Would appreciate CKAN Installation from Source on RedHat instructions which were successfully utilized.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could try this one : https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.x-on-CentOS-7

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem? We recently did the same with version 2.8 and it was a walk through dependency hell. What we had to do was to combine 2 wikis (the one posted by Julien), the official homepage, and some other sources.

Comment: Lukas, thank you for your post. We have one problem after another.
Latest is 
In step 2-d of https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html & trying to run below pip command after you installed CKAN. But the requirements.txt file is not found.
Step 2-d: Install the Python modules that CKAN requires into your virtualenv:
pip install -r /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/requirements.txt
I checked here as well but its empty - /root/ckan/lib/default/src  .

Could you please share your consolidated instruction document? Much appreciated!

Comment: That file should be right in your install folder. Unfortunatly we didn't write down our findings. We just fixed it as we encountered the problems.

Comment: @LukasStampf any chance you could add your setup steps (even rough notes) to the CKAN wikis? https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki. It would be great to update and expand the _"How to Install on ..."_ pages.